# When a page fault happens in user application, what is current pid when kernel handler this fault

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, malloc, page-fault

I run a user app simply like this:

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100000);
int *a = (int *)buf;
int i = 0;
for(; i < 100000; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}
```

I think it surely triggers page fault since malloc will not alloc a real physical space until we touch this data.

And I modified the linux kernel(3.17.6) 
mm/memory.c : handle_pte_fault() like this

```
if (targetPid == current->pid)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "soso : targetPid : %d, current->pid : %d\n", targetPid, current->pid);
```

Here "tartgetPid" is the user app pid that I passed into kernel, 
"current" is the macro of kernel

But this line never triggered, because when kernel handle page fault, it's current pid will not be the pid of that user app which trigger a page fault.

I'd like to ask 
When a page fault happens in user application, what is current pid when kernel handler this fault

Comment: what printing of current->pid shows?

Comment: Some other number instead of targetPid

Comment: How do you pass the targetPid into the kernel?